# High memory & network usage when providing unique node names for celery nodes

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a production environment with three hosts, each running 4 celery processes bound to various queues. I'm using rabbitmq as a broker and the latest celery version (3.1.23).

The normal system load is about 150 messages/sec published and consumed.
rabbitmq network throughput is about 30 Mb/sec

I did not set a unique name for the celery nodes, and was receiving a warning such as:

`A node named celery@export_000 is already using this process mailbox!`

After providing a unique name for each celery process by adding the %h to the hostname variable, the warning was resolved but the system become unusable due to very high memory and network usage.

The memory usage of the celery processes peaked (4GB -> 30GB) to whatever was available on the machine even for processes that weren't performing any tasks.
Network peaked to 0.5 Gb/sec on the rabbit host even though there was no abnormal queue utilization. If anything, celery consumers did not consume any messages.

Consumers seemed busy mainly syncing with each other (according to logs) and occasionally performing a few tasks.

Reverting back to the non-unique node names immediately solved the issue.

Related celery [ticket](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3266)

Any ideas what could be causing this?
Can the celery node sync process be related to it somehow?